# How to speed .NET MVC site deployed on AZURE?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, azure, azure-sql-database

Of course i want to reach maximum perfomance.
What can I do for it?

1. Use Bundles for CSS & JS files? Ok.
2. What kind of storage shold I use? Now its SQL Database. 
   But site and DB are placed in different regions. Size of DB will be not too big -1 gb - is enough. And - how to reduce query-time. Now - it's too long.
3. Should I turn on "always on" feature for my site?
4. Is there anything else? Is the any article ti read?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to profile first.

Comment: There is not one _"make my site fast"_ checklist. As @sharptooth indicates, _you_ need to analyze why certain parts of your site are slow (hint: [YSlow](http://yslow.org/), SQL Profiler) and see what you can do to fix that. This is too broad for SO anyway, though you can ask for help with specific issues.

Comment: Use the F12 tools in your browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc) - it includes a Network graph feature which shows how long each resource takes to return and where any possible delays are.

Comment: After moving db & site to same DC (and this DC is closest to me) - site become ultafast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only so much optimization you can do - if you really want "maximum performance" then you'd rewrite your site in C/C++ as a kext or driver-service and store all of your data in `memcached`, or maybe encode your entire website as a series of millions of individual high-frequency electronic logic-gates all etched into an integrated circuit and hooked-up directly to a network interface...

...now that we're on realistic terms ;) your posting has the main performance-issue culprit right there: your database and webserver are not local to each other, which is a problem: every webpage users request is going to trigger a database request, and if the database is more than a few miliseconds away then it's going to cause problems (MSSQL Server has a rather chatty network protocol too, which multiplies the latency effect considerably).

Ideally, total page generation time from request-sent to response-arrived should be under 100ms before users will notice your site being "slow". Considering that a webserver might be 30ms or more from the client, that means you have approximately 50-60ms to generate the page, which means your database server has to be within 0-3ms of your webserver. Even 5ms latency is too great because something as innocuous as 3-4 database queries is going to incur a delay of at least `4 * ( 5ms + DB read time)ms` - DB read-time can vary from 0ms (if the data is in memory) or up to 20ms if it's on a slow platter drive, or even slower depending on server-load - that's how you can easily find a "simple" website taking over 100ms just to generate on the server, let alone send to the client.

In short: move your DB to a server on the same local network as your webserver to reduce the latency.

Comment: same local network - in terms of Azure - what is it? Central US, East Asia - the only way. Is there more specific places?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate and simplest way to start in your conditions is to move the database and the site in the same datacenter.
Later you may think to:

- INSTRUMENT YOUR CODE
- Add (Azure Redis) Cache
- Load balance your web site (if it is charged enough)
- And everything around compacting/bundling/minimizing your code.

Hope it helps,